# circle from UIBezierPath drawn in wrong direction in SKShapeNode

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, uibezierpath, skshapenode

Following [UIBezierPath](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIBezierPath_class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIBezierPath/bezierPathWithArcCenter:radius:startAngle:endAngle:clockwise:) reference, I tried drawing a dashed path which should end up as dashed arc. However the drawing direction is wrong. `clockwise` was set to true but the top half of the circle was drawn as opposed to what was mentioned in the apple's page

```
let arcForCompleted =
        UIBezierPath(arcCenter: origin, radius: radius, startAngle: 0, endAngle: CGFloat(M_PI), clockwise: true)
let pattern = getPattern(self.circumference, segments: involved)
let dashedPathForCompleted = CGPathCreateCopyByDashingPath(arcForCompleted.CGPath, nil, 0, pattern, pattern.count)
let dashedCircleForCompleted = SKShapeNode(path: dashedPathForCompleted!)
```

I am guessing this is because UIKit and SpriteKit has different coordinate system.

Comment: Please add some more code.

Answer (score 4):

UIBezierPath is written with UIKit in mind thus it uses the UIKit coordinate system, (0,0) is in the upper left with positive y values running down. For the SKNode it has different coordinate system, (0,0) is in the center with positive y running up. You should keep that in mind when drawing arcs as it will affect the clockwise parameter. You can find a discussion of SKNode coordinate system [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/SpriteKit_PG/Nodes/Nodes.html).

You can paste this code in a playground to see the difference as well

```
let bezierPath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: 50.0,y: 50.0), radius: 50, startAngle: 0, endAngle: CGFloat(M_PI), clockwise: true)
class ArcView:UIView
{
    override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
        let arcForCompleted = bezierPath
        let pattern:[CGFloat] = [10.0,10.0]
        arcForCompleted.setLineDash(pattern, count: 2, phase: 0.0)
        arcForCompleted.stroke()
    }
}
let arcView = ArcView(frame: CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: 100.0, height: 100.0))
arcView.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

let arcForCompleted = bezierPath
let shape = SKShapeNode()
shape.path = arcForCompleted.CGPath
```